# find contiguous ranges with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of values (numeric) of different customers (customer_id):

```
CREATE TABLE dev.customer_resources (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customer_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  value int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to get the ranges of numbers for a specific customer.
so, if the table data is:

```
======================
|id|customer_id|value|
======================
| 1|         21|    1|
----------------------
| 2|         21|    2|
----------------------
| 3|         21|    3|
----------------------
| 4|         21|   20|
----------------------
| 5|         21|   21|
----------------------
| 6|         21|   22|
----------------------
| 7|         22|    5|
----------------------
```

i'll get a result that is something like this, for customer_id=21:

```
==========
start |end
==========
|    1| 3|
----------
|   20|22|
----------
```

and something like this for customer_id=22:

```
==========
start |end
==========
|    5| 5|
----------
```

After searching for a solution, i found the following code:

```
select l.value as start,
    (
        select min(a.value) as value
        from customer_resources as a
            left outer join customer_resources as b on a.value = b.value - 1
        where b.value is null
            and a.value >= l.value
    ) as end
from customer_resources as l
    left outer join customer_resources as r on r.value = l.value - 1
where r.value is NULL;
```

that does pretty much what i need, but does not include limiting the results to a specific customer_id.
I tried adding the customer_id to the query, but i'm not quite sure where to add it, as all it did was break functionality.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: thanks for the feedback. edited the question.

Comment: And, what have you tried?

Comment: thought it may be better leaving this open to other ideas, but now added the code i'm already using.

Comment: That doesn't look quite right to me. If no one beats me to it, I'll post an alternative solution on Monday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LukStorms solution seems like the right kind of thing - it just seems a little more convoluted than is strictly necessary...

Here's a variation on the theme...

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

    CREATE TABLE my_table
    (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    ,customer_id int NOT NULL
    ,value int NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
    (1,         21,    1),
    (2,         21,    2),
    (3,         21,    3),
    (4,         21,   20),
    (5,         21,   21),
    (6,         21,   22),
    (7,         22,    5);

    SELECT customer_id
         , MIN(value) start
         , MAX(value) end 
      FROM 
         ( SELECT *
                , CASE WHEN value = @prev+1 THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END grp
                , @prev:=value prev
             FROM my_table
                , (SELECT @prev:= null,@i:=0) vars 
            ORDER 
               BY customer_id
                , id
         ) x 
     GROUP 
        BY customer_id,grp;
    +-------------+-------+------+
    | customer_id | start | end  |
    +-------------+-------+------+
    |          21 |     1 |    3 |
    |          21 |    20 |   22 |
    |          22 |     5 |    5 |
    +-------------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Nice. +1 Much more golfcoded than mine. I like it.  At a glance I assumed this would give the wrong result in some cases. F.e. if you change the insert (7,22,5) to (7,22,23).  Then customer_id 22 would also be in grp 2. But because it's grouped in the outer query by customer_id & grp the MIN will still return the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a Gaps And Islands problem.

Here's a bit of old-school MySql specific solution that makes use of variables.

The start of an island is found by comparing the previous value and customer_id.

```sql
SELECT 
 customer_id, 
 value_start as `start`, 
 max(val) as `end`
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
      CASE 
      WHEN `value` = @prev_val + 1 AND customer_id = @prev_grp
      THEN @start_val:= @start_val 
      ELSE @start_val:=`value`
      END AS value_start, 
      @prev_grp:=customer_id as customer_id,
      @prev_val:=`value` as val
    FROM customer_resources
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_val:=NULL, @start_val:=NULL, @prev_grp:=NULL) AS v
    ORDER BY customer_id, `value`
) AS q 
GROUP BY customer_id, value_start;
```

Comment: thank you! I will go with Strawberrys' solution, as you too recommended.

Comment: Thx. And good choice. If you compare the result of the sub-queries between the 2 solutions.  Then you'll notice that we tried to calculate something different. I made it harder on myself by trying to get the first value in connected numbers per customer.  While his query just gets a ranking per connected numbers. Simple is often best.